# How to upload all flavor aar files with gradle uploadArchives task?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build-flavors, android-flavors

I have android library project with different flavors. Each of flavor relate a different server url.

I want to build different aars and upload all of them to Nexus. But I don't know how to select all productFlavors when uploadArchives executed.

If somebody knows the ways how to solve my problem, please help me, thanks!

Here is build.gradle in library:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    configurations {
        all {
            exclude module: 'httpclient'
            exclude module: 'commons-logging'
            exclude module: 'xpp3'
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "server"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            versionNameSuffix "dev"
            buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://dev.path.com\"")
        }
        qa {
            versionNameSuffix "test"
            buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://test.path.com\"")
        }
        prod {
            versionNameSuffix "demo"
            buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://demo.path.com\"")
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.23"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

uploadArchives task works fine without flavor

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "http://nexus.path") {
                authentication(userName: "name", password: "pass")
                pom.groupId = "groupId"
                pom.artifactId = "core"
                pom.version = '0.0.23'
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But It doesn't work after I added flavorDimensions.

I need upload all my aars to Nexus with different artifactId or version.
I'd like to use it in my other projects something like this:

```
implementation "groupId:core.dev:0.0.23"
implementation "groupId:core.qa:0.0.23"
implementation "groupId:core.prod:0.0.23"
```

or

```
implementation "groupId:core:0.0.23-dev"
implementation "groupId:core:0.0.23-qa"
implementation "groupId:core:0.0.23-prod"
```

When it's possible, help me, please.